# Pass value to from ajax call to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'test.php',
 type: "POST",
 data: registerForm.serialize(), region: $("#regio option:selected").text(),
 success: function(data) {
 console.log(data)
 }
});
```

Now i use this i get all data with `registerForm.serialize()` i can call them in test.php with `$_POST['the_name'];`

Now i need to pass to test.php `$("#regio option:selected").text()` whenever i do `echo $_POST['region']` in test.php it doesnt see the region attribute where im sending inside the ajax to test.php.

How do i pass `$("#regio option:selected").text()` to test.php and call it in test.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add another query string into that:

```
data: registerForm.serialize() + '&region=' + $("#regio option:selected").text(),
```

Then, just treat it like a normal post value in PHP

```
$region = $_POST['region'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's re-indent the code:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   type: "POST",
   data: registerForm.serialize(), 
   region: $("#regio option:selected").text(),
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data)
   }
});
```

The above code defines a `region` property on the object that has been passed to `$.ajax()`. The `region` property doesn't belong to the `data` property, in fact your `data` property is not even an object. As the other answer suggests you can add another query parameter by using string concatenation, or use the `serializeArray` method and push an object into the returned array:

```
// returns an array of objects with `name` and `value` properties 
var postData = registerForm.serializeArray();
postData.push({
   name: 'region',
   value: $("#regio option:selected").text()
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'test.php',
   type: "POST",
   data: postData, 
   success: function(responseData) {
      console.log(responseData);
   }
});
```